# how to make my Facebook chatbot available for download

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I want to make my bot available for download for testing purpose without 
going through the actual review process of Facebook? This is just for testing purpose as I want to test how exactly end user will 
download my bot from FB messenger platform and then will start using my bot. Is there a way/platform to try this? Can I do that?
(currently i am testing am sending message to my bot using FB page's messenger link as indicated in almost all the blogs/sites including FB's official
site.)

Can you please provide any pointers/links on this?

Comment: What do you even mean by “downloading” in this context? Bots are not “downloaded.”

Comment: Let me clarify. My requirement is user can have Facebook messenger app on their mobile where they can search for publically available chatbots(I checked like CNN chatbot, Spring or other already available chatbots.), I want my chatbot to be available publically. But before going for the complete review process by submitting all the required details to Facebook I want to check how end user will access/use my chatbot on mobile. Is there any way to do that? Currently I have done testing of my chatbot using FB page's messenger link.

Comment: You can't download a chatbot, unless what you mean by that is downloading the bot's source code. The only way to interact with a chatbot is through Facebook Messenger. If you're trying to test it, add the testers' Facebook accounts to the tester role under roles for the app. You can have up to 500 testers, so hopefully that is enough for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for you:

1. You want users to test your bot on Messenger:

   Simply add them as testers in your bot corresponding Facebook page then ask them to look for your bot in their Messenger app.
2. Or you want to test your bot behaviors:

   Enter [bot*gen*](https://codename.co/botgen/designer/) the chatbot generator I'm currently working on, which could help you test more publicly the bot you're working on. *(assuming your bot doesn't need coding and is all about pattern conversation)*.

   Just use the designer interface to design, run and test your chatbot.
   Publish it and share it with your actual test users.

Comment: whats that botgen? looks like a modified version of rivescript and superscript to me. are you gonna make method calls asynchronous in that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Going through review process and guidelines. Between do i need to develop my chatbot app as Android platform 
app? Currently its a server java app. I was checking about video creation of my running chatbot and was not getting how can i run 
it on mobile. I know i may be missing basics here but but request to please guide. One more question - Do I need to implement OAuth2 in my chatbot for user authentication? Thanks in advance for help and inputs.